# Add event to Dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, html, events

Nees some advice.

Need to pass an event to onclick of span depending on my condition. Please help.

here is my current code:

```
var evt1 = true;

var my_evt = (evt1 ? function () { alert('test'); } : null);

var str = "<span onclick=my_evt></span>";
```

thanks.

Comment: What span? Where is the HTML code?

Comment: var str = '<span onclick=my_evt></span>

Comment: sorry when i first tried to post my html code it disapears.

Comment: @user1215811 You need to use the code formatting button to add HTML (or format it yourself via 4x indent on each line).

Comment: Thanks you Marty for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just check the condition inside the event handler and do nothing if it is false?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have the click execute some code when `evt1` is true, I'd advise just putting code in the `onclick` of the *actual* span in the HTML itself.

```
<span onclick="if (evt1) { myEvt() }">...</span>
```

Dynamically building up HTML in Javascript is usually going to "anger the hungry one". And especially if that HTML itself contains yet more Javascript. It's a bit of a nightmare.

But if your heart is set on it, here's one way to do it:

```
var str;
if (evt1) {
  str = "<span onclick=\"function() { alert('test'); } \"></span>";
} else {
  str = "<span></span>";
}
```

In general though, you'd have to have a pretty good reason for using this approach, given that the string has to eventually make its way into an HTML document to be useful.

You can also build up strings like this:

```
var str = "<span" + (evt1 ? " onclick=\"function () { alert('test'); }\"" : "") + "></span>";
```

But again, this is  ... nothing short of *horrendous* coding style.